# Where can I get non-enchanted Hooded Mage's Robes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't seem to find an non-enchanted version of this outfit anywhere. It is the same clothing all court wizards use, but I need an non-enchanted version (preferably without using the console), so that I can enchant it myself.

Has anyone come across any non-enchanted Hooded Mage's Robes? Can they even be found in a non-enchanted form?

Comment: Perhaps a word on why you need it?  To fulfill a quest (which one)?

Comment: i like the look of the robes but i want to enchant them myself.

Comment: By unenchanted do you mean it doesn't give you a boost to magkica...? Because I don't believe such a thing exists. I believe all mage robes give some form of magic bonus.

Comment: @Wipqozn I've found unenchanted robes before - they do exist.  Can't say where or what color though...

Comment: @Wipqozn yes i mean completely unenchanted so i can enchant it myself.

Comment: a hooded robe isn't as good as a none hooded robe as it takes up the head slot too.  If you go with a none hooded robe you can wear an enchanted circlet or mask or something

Comment: Question: Does a hood and robe look different from a hooded robe? Or is it just the color you like?

Comment: @agf hooded robe is all in 1 meaning you can wear a circlet with it hood and robe you cant.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't wear anything on your head with a hooded robe. See yx.'s comment.

Comment: I seem to recall finding one about a week ago and thinking of this post. I'm not a 100% sure, but I think it was Fellglow Keep I was in doing the "Hitting the books" quest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't find one try entering `coc qasmoke` in the console, and look in the standard equipment. If it exists, it will be in there, if not, you're out of luck. Remember, you don't have to take anything, just see if it exists or not. **Warning:** Don't open the enchanted armour/weapons cabinet, as it may crash or lag your game.

Comment: thanks for the info i didnt think of that, does going into the testing room have any bad effects?

Comment: @I Phantasm I — The main downsides are (a) as dark warns, some of the cabinets have large enough inventories to severely lag or even crash the game; and (b) it *is* cheating, and it's up to you whether you're okay with that.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a clothing store in Solitude, with a sign of a ball of yarn closest store from where you fast travel too, they sell all random clothing items. I've found a few "Hoods" from there. And anyone saying they don't sell them empty is ridiculous, thats the entire point of enchanting and you can only make the best mage armor by enchanting them yourself

Answer (score 3):

Enthir in the mages college sells non-enchanted robes, but can only be found or obtained if high in speech. They also cost a pretty penny with speech all the way to 100 with no perks a master robe with no enchantments is roughly 5000 gold. Hoped this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to fellglow keep, in the circular room with all of the bookshelves there is one pair of unenchanted hooded black robes. They are the only ones in the entire game. Good luckTo you. And yes you can get them even if you have already been there. Happy questing!

Answer (score 1):

I dont recall finding any non-enchanted robes in my Skyrim journey so far.  I just went to the Radiant Raiment in Solitude to look and see what they have.  They DO have a Blue Robe but it is not hooded.  I hope that I am wrong so that you can get the look your going for.

Comment: yeah i have been to Raiment's a couple of times and they seem to not sell any hooded robes at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do exist, I just went into Radiant Rainments in Solitude, and found them.

They are called College Robes, and cost me 28 gold. Keep looking if you haven't found them yet.

Answer (score 1):

Defeat Mayln Veran and take his robes before the star kicks you out. I just got mine for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a blue and black set at the general store in Winterhold. I've found quite a few, not sure where the rest were though.

Answer (score 0):

There are no unenchanted hooded or unhooded thalmor robes in the game.
However i know where you are coming from with the look, i like to roll thalmor gear too.
Heres what i do, over enchant the stats on the gear you can (rings, gloves, boots, circlet) and roll the thalmor robes regardless. With the beefy stats on the gear you can enchant, you arent going to miss much when it comes to the states you can enchant on robes (magic regen and minus destruction cost).

Answer (score 0):

I kill the annoying monk in whiterun and I steal his nice yellow hooded robe, and then I enchant myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill some monks in a temple and then buy the mage hood from Colette Marence. Each time it respawns, it will be a higher level.